# Can't access method because it is less accessible - c#

Tags: c#, forms, struct

I'm writing a form in c# that must access all internal classes containig a struct.
The error I get is on this lines:

```
public frmSelectMusic(int mode, Module.MusicData data)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    switch (mode)
    {
        case 1:
            this.Text = "BGM";
            compileList("BGM");
            break;
        case 2:
            this.Text = "BGS";
            compileList("BGS");
            break;
        case 3:
            this.Text = "ME";
            compileList("ME");
            break;
        case 4:
            this.Text = "SE";
            compileList("SE");
            break;
    }
    this.mode = mode;
    if (data.name != "")
    {
        if (objList.Items.Contains(data.name))
        {
            objList.SelectedItem = data.name;
            cmdVolume.Value = data.volume / 10;
            cmdPitch.Value = (data.pitch - 50) / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the module:

```
internal class Module
{
    internal static string mainPath;
    internal static string projectPath;

    internal struct MusicData
    {
        public int type;
        public string name;
        public int volume;
        public int pitch;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Should I use public instead of internal in the module?

Comment: Is it in a different namespace?

Comment: Is the MusicData struct in a different assembly? If so, yes you need to switch to public.

Comment: No, both files resides in the same namespace.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the namespace is irrelevant.  What matters is that the types be defined in the same *assembly* (or "friend" assemblies, defined with the InternalsVisibleTo attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct `MusicData` is defined as an internal struct of an internal class `Module`.

So there is no way you can access something public if 'the path' to the function is blocked by a "lower" access modifier(internal).

The internal access modifier basically grants access to anyone in the same assembly, while the public access modifier grants access to everyone.

So you either need to change your internals into publics or change your public into an internal.

Read some more [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Module and Module.MusicData classes are internal so are visible only by code within the same assembly, and frmSelectMusic constructor is public so can be seen by everyone. This public constructor (which can be seen by everyone) takes as an argument Module.MusicData struct which can't be seen by everyone, there is a conflict. So you should either change frmSelectMusic constructor to internal, or Module and Module.MusicData classes to public.